# Button onClickListener causes runtime error without pressing it

Tags: java, android, button, runtime-error, onclicklistener

I'm trying to make an app where a loop generates arithmetic expressions and list them as individual TextViews in linear layout. After tapping on one of the expressions a popup window comes up with that expression and an input field for the user to input a solution. Underneath there is a button to submit the solution. I have the button positioned in XML. The problem is that when I use onClickListener, the app crashes in the moment when I tap on the expression for the window to popup. If I remove the whole onClickListener then window comes up, but button is functionless. 
This causes error:

```
Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answerWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

And this is the rest of the function:

```
    package klosinski.kamil.arithmeticproblems;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class QuizGenerate extends AppCompatActivity {



   boolean usePlus, useMinus, useMult, useDivide;
   int count, maxValue;
   Equation equation[] = new Equation[20];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_generate);

        SharedPreferences quizSettings = getSharedPreferences("QuizSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);

        usePlus = quizSettings.getBoolean("usePlus", true);
        useMinus = quizSettings.getBoolean("useMinus", true);
        useMult = quizSettings.getBoolean("useMult", true);
        useDivide = quizSettings.getBoolean("useDivide", true);
        count = quizSettings.getInt("count",0);
        maxValue = quizSettings.getInt("maxValue",0);
        generateQuiz(); //Populate Equation class with generated equations
        displayQuiz(); //Display the equations to the screen
    }

    //Method to display the contents of Equation class to the screen
    public void displayQuiz(){
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewx);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            int value1 = equation[i].getValue1();
            int value2 = equation[i].getValue2();
            char operator = equation[i].getOperator();

            String value1Str = Integer.toString(value1);
            String value2Str = Integer.toString(value2);

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.equationSize));
            if(operator == '/'){
                operator = '\u00F7';
            }
            textView.setText(value1Str + " " + operator + " " + value2Str + "=");
            textView.setId(i);
            textView.setOnClickListener(displayAnswerForm);
            textView.setClickable(true);

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
        this.setContentView(scrollView);
    }

    // OnClickListener runs after equation is pressed.
    // Displays a popup window with the pressed equation and editText for answer.
    public View.OnClickListener displayAnswerForm = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);

            // Create the popup window
            int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;  // Width of the popup window
            int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; // Height of the popup window
            final PopupWindow answerWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, true);

            int equationTextViewId= v.getId(); // The ID of the text view that was pressed

            // Getting the values and operator to display as equation.
            String value1 = Integer.toString(equation[equationTextViewId].getValue1());
            String value2 = Integer.toString(equation[equationTextViewId].getValue2());
            char operator = equation[equationTextViewId].getOperator();
            // If operator is a '/' (divide) then display it as a divider symbol.
            if(operator == '/'){
                operator = '\u00F7';
            }
            String equationToDisplay = value1+" "+operator+" "+value2+"="; // Complete string with the equation.

            //Display our equation on the popup window.
            ((TextView)answerWindow.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.answerWindowTextView)).setText(equationToDisplay);


            // Display the popup window.
            answerWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


            ////
            ////
            //// setOnClickListener or the function causes a crash.
            ////
            ////
            Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);
            btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    answerWindow.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }

    };


    //Method to populate Equation class with generated equations
    public void generateQuiz(){

        char operator = '+';

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            switch(getRandomNumber(1, 4)){
                case 1:
                    operator = '+';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    operator = '-';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    operator = '*';
                    break;
                case 4:
                    operator = '/';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            equation[i] = new Equation(getRandomNumber(1, maxValue), getRandomNumber(1, maxValue), operator);
        }
    }

    private int getRandomNumber(int min,int max) {
        return (new Random()).nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }



}
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answerWindowTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="5 + 2="
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorEditText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="eg. 28"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.527"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/answerWindowTextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="DONE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText8" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Google has lead me to a few "related" topics, but none helped me. Might it be something to do with the View?

Regards,
Kamil

@edit

```
08-02 15:50:18.731 12741-12741/klosinski.kamil.arithmeticproblems E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: klosinski.kamil.arithmeticproblems, PID: 12741
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at klosinski.kamil.arithmeticproblems.QuizGenerate$1.onClick(QuizGenerate.java:110)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22565)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: @ADM Thank you. I've added the Logcat.

Comment: This is not the crash trace . Select `Error` in `LogCat` and only post error log .

Comment: btnDone is null. Show the complete XML

Comment: And also show the part where you inflate your layout. Or where you do the setContentView()

Comment: Thank you all for corrections. I have added the complete code and XML. @G.Kalender

Comment: You shouldn't use setContentView(); like this. Only call it once, only in onCreate(). If you want to change the content, use fragments or start another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `at klosinski.kamil.arithmeticproblems.QuizGenerate$1.onClick(QuizGenerate.java:110)` tells you that the crash happened at QuizGenerate.java file at line 110

The error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference` suggests that the btnDone is null.

findViewById would work only if the view that you are looking for belongs to the current context in scope. i.e. If you are calling findViewById within an Activity then the view should belong to the activity otherwise it will return null. If you are calling findViewById within a Fragment then the view should belong to the fragment otherwise it will return null. You get the point.

So make sure that you are calling `Button btnDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);` from the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use setContentView(); like this. Only call it once, only in onCreate(). If you want to change the content, use fragments or start another activity. if you change the content, you can't find your views via findViewById anymore.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, I removed the line `this.setContentView(scrollView);` and it made no difference to the output. Perhaps it was there pointlessly. I am now reading the documentation regarding Fragments, as I haven't touched it before, and I think it will work better than Popup Window. Can I ask for your opinion? Thanks once again

Comment: If I understand your app idea correctly, it is totally fine to use an activity that has the list with arithmetic expressions and on click you open a dialog. You don't necessarily need fragments here, I just pointed that out for switching contents. I think you should take a deeper look into these two topics: 1. Implement list with RecyclerView and 2. Show custom dialog. You can follow these links to read further: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview and https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs (especially the custom laoyut part).